# Azure Functions in Visual Studio - How to add reference to another project

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function project in Visual Studio. I am trying to reference an entity framework model project that we already use. Someone that is no longer with the company has accomplished this feat as you can see in the image below:

[image]

However when trying to create a new project, I am unable to add this project reference. I am able to add the project to the solution normally (right clicking the solution file and clicking "Add Project", however I am unable to reference any of the code from that project inside of the azure function code.

[image]

As you can see there is no "Projects" drop down, and there is no option in the context menu that corresponds to adding projects.

The azure project is v2 using netcoreapp2.1, whereas the project I wish to reference is net4.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions V2 can only reference NetCore compatible projects, if you want an external library to be referenced in your Functions project, you need to declare that library as either a .NetCore or even .NetStandard library. 
A project built on Net4.6 is just too old to be referenced in a .NetCore project.

Comment: WOW, so my 5 million line of codes proejct witten 7 years ago (.Net Frameworks) must be converted to .NetStandard  to use Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1):

It look like the first Azure function that was able to reference the project was a version 1 azure function written in .Net 4.62 or so.

Your V2 function being .net Core would not be able to reference a .net project/assembly that was written in a 4.xx version of .Net.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Right, so is there any way to do it in the current set up? You cant use V2 with .net462 right?

Comment: @JacobAlley I think that the best that you can do is convert the model project to a .net standard library which would be able to be used by both Core and 4.xx